# Add views past date filter dropdown

Tags: 7, views

Tried if someone has already faced or tried for this but I could not find any forum discussion around this.

Within Drupal views I am trying to add date filter based on a CCK date field. I am trying to add date filter within views like:

- Past 7 days
- Past one month
- Past 3 months
- Past 6 months
- Past one year

I don't see any modules to achieve this neither any discussion around this

Answer (score 1):

The [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module has a submodule called **Date Views** that allows Views integration with Date fields.

Once enabled, you should be able to add an **Exposed**, **Grouped** filter on your date field. For each grouped filter, you can add your **Label** (e.g. "Past 7 days"), **Operator** (*is between*), & **Value** which you can set to Relative dates that match your label (e.g. **From:** "-7 day" / **To:** "now").

Comment: I do have Date Views module enabled. But I don't have an views operator as "is between" in Drupal 7.

Comment: I have also tried installing the module: views_between_dates_filter but again no luck.

Comment: Is your field data stored as a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: @AnAnD try adding [Authored On](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VA2uq.jpg) you should get an `is between` option there.

Comment: @No Sssweat, As I am using a CCK filed which is indexed in Apache Solr I  have to use only that field to filter the nodes based on date. I can't use any other date field